# data must be QuerySet-like (have count() and order_by()) or support list(data) -- NoneType has neither

Tags: python, django

I am using Django-table2 for SingleTableMixin and I am getting this error which I  am not able to come around. Error says I need to present data in query to be able to make it work. Following is the code and guidance is requested.

```
class ProductListView(SingleTableMixin, generic.TemplateView):

    template_name = 'dashboard/catalogue/product_list.html'
    form_class = ProductSearchForm
    productclass_form_class = ProductClassSelectForm
    table_class = ProductTable
    context_table_name = 'products'

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        ctx = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['form'] = self.form
        ctx['productclass_form'] = self.productclass_form_class()
        return ctx

    def get_description(self, form):
        if form.is_valid() and any(form.cleaned_data.values()):
            return _('Product search results')
        return _('Products')

    def get_table(self, **kwargs):
        if 'recently_edited' in self.request.GET:
            kwargs.update(dict(orderable=False))

        table = super(ProductListView, self).get_table(**kwargs)
        table.caption = self.get_description(self.form)
        return table

    def get_table_pagination(self):
        return dict(per_page=20)

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):

        return filter_products(queryset, self.request.user)

    def get_queryset(self):

        queryset = Product.browsable.base_queryset()
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)
        queryset = self.apply_search(queryset)
        return queryset
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in get
  158.         context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\AliKhan\supermarket\market\dashboard\catalogue\views.py" in get_context_data
  77.         ctx = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_tables2\views.py" in get_context_data
  107.         table = self.get_table(**self.get_table_kwargs())
File "C:\Users\AliKhan\supermarket\market\dashboard\catalogue\views.py" in get_table
  91.         table = super(ProductListView, self).get_table(**kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_tables2\views.py" in get_table
  82.         table = table_class(self.get_table_data(), **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_tables2\tables.py" in __init__
  348.         self.data = self.TableDataClass(data=data, table=self)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_tables2\tables.py" in __init__
  45.             ' list(data) -- {} has neither'.format(type(data).__name__)

Exception Type: ValueError at /dashboard/catalogue/
Exception Value: data must be QuerySet-like (have count() and order_by()) or support list(data) -- NoneType has neither
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Django settings.py is not able to collect django-table2 and its dependencies. Try to import it from shell. Code has no issues. Are you trying virtualenv? If yes then which OS? If that is Windows then you must install django-oscar globally before you try it in virtualenv.

Comment: From shell it is importing. I also am using PyCharm IDE and if import fails it shows flags but it is not showing any flags for failed import.

Comment: Still install it globally and then try. Your code as I've told you earlier has no issues.

Comment: It did worked and it doesn't make any sense to me. Can you tell me why this kind of behavior?